# Initializing a List

Tags: c#, .net, list

I have created a class  `student` with three properties like this

```
public class Student
{
    public int age;
    public string name;
    public string course;

    public Student(int age , string name , string course)
    {
        this.age = age;
        this.course = course;
        this.name = name;
    }

    List<Student> school = new List<Student>(
        new Student(12,"ram","ece"));                        
        );
}
```

what I am trying to do is, I am adding student details manually to student class

but I am getting this error at this line

```
  new Student(12,"ram","ece"));
```

> **Error  :**   cannot convert from `windowsapplication.student`   to   `systems.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<windowsapplication.Student>`

Why is this happening?

Comment: Minor note:  those are fields, not properties.  In C#, properties have get/set methods.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The syntax you have used is trying to pass a new `Student` to the constructor of `List<Student>` - there is no such constructor, hence the error.

You have a small syntax error. This should work:

```
List<Student> school = new List<Student>{
                        new Student(12,"ram","ece"));                        
                       };
```

The syntax for collection initializer is with `{}` not `()`.

Comment: many thanks i have tried this its working now .... waiting for 7 minutes to tick an answer..

Comment: @MikeNakis - The default constructor (no parameters constructor) is added by the compiler. If you want to learn more about this kind of thing, C# in depth (2nd edition) by Jon Skeet is an excellent book.

Answer (score 1):

`List<Student>` constructor is expecting `IEnumerable<Student>`, not a single student. I think you actually wanted to use list initializer syntax:

```
List<Student> school = new List<Student>()
{
    new Student(12,"ram","ece"),
};
```

Answer (score 1):

try

```
List<Student> school = new List<Student>() { new Student(12,"ram","ece") };
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
List<Student> school = new List<Student>();
school.add(new Student(12,"ram","ece"));
```

Comment: Where did the `School` class come from?  And you're trying to add a `Student` to a list of Schools.